# How to handle TokenMismatch exception in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, exception, laravel-5, token

Currently I am Working on laravel Project

and I got irritate to see this error on page.

I don't my users to see this exception even I have taken care about this.

But Prevention is better than cure!

So is there any way to handle this Exception in laravel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `Exception\Handler` class in the `render()` method catch this exception via

```
if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {
   // Your code
}
```

And render your error page or do any other stuff with this exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need the CSRF protection you can disable the middleware in

> app/Http/Kernel.php

If you set your application environment to production later, the users wont see the error messages anyway.

Answer (score -1):

To Handle this exception go to your_laravel_folder/vendor/compiled.php
and find this ::

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
   if ($this->isReading($request) || $this->tokensMatch($request)) {
       return $this->addCookieToResponse($request, $next($request));
   }
        throw new TokenMismatchException();
}
```

and comment  throw new TokenMismatchException(); and Do what you want here is the example

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
   if ($this->isReading($request) || $this->tokensMatch($request)) {
      return $this->addCookieToResponse($request, $next($request));
   }
    abort(404);
    //throw new TokenMismatchException();
}
```